# Solve riddle in prolog

Tags: prolog, zebra-puzzle

I want to solve this riddle in prolog:

> The students Lily, Jack and Daisy go to the same university. All of them come from a different country and have different hobbies. They all go to a university in the USA, where one of them is living. Lily has better grades then the one who comes from Italy. Jack has better grades then the one who likes reading books. The best grades has the one who likes football. Jack comes from Germany and Daisy likes cooking.
>
> Who is who (name, country, hobby, grades)?

The correct solution should be:

- Lily, USA, Reading Books, Grade 2
- Jack, Germany, Football, Grade 1
- Daisy, Italy, Cooking, Grade 3

The Problem I have right now is that I don't know how I could solve this riddle. How should I define the facts and what's the best way to solve the riddle?

Answer (score 2):

The trick to answer these puzzle questions in Prolog is to generate (retrieve) possible answers and then test them against the logical constraints. So, if Lily is person P1, then retrieve any person P2 and test if that person is from italy.  And so forth with the other rules.

That means, in first instance, you need some clauses with possible countries, possible hobbies and possible grades.  Not all possibilities are necessary, because some are already ruled out by the question.

The solution below, based on arbitrarily making Lily person 1, Jack person 2 and Daisy person 3.

Load in to Prolog and query who(P1,C1,H1,G1, P2,C2,H2,G2, P3,C3,H3,G3).

```
country(italy).
country(usa).
hobby(football).
hobby(reading).
grade(c:1).
grade(b:2).
grade(a:3).



who(lily,C1,H1,Grade1, jack,germany,H2,Grade2, daisy,C3,cooking,Grade3):-
    country(C1), country(C3), C1 \= C3,
    hobby(H1), hobby(H2), H1 \= H2,
    grade(G1:Grade1), grade(G2:Grade2), grade(G3:Grade3),
    G1 \= G2, G2 \= G3, G1 \= G3,
    (C3=italy, G1@>G3),
    (H1=reading, G2@>G1),
    ((H1=football, G1@>G2, G1@>G3); (H2=football, G2@>G1, G2@>G3)).
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know if it is right to say H1=reading or C3=italy, because Prolog should solve this puzzle. Is there any other possibility?

Comment: when you query prolog, it finds answers for the variables in your query.  So, use the following queru

Comment: When you query in Prolog it finds the answers for the variables.  So, enter the following query in Prolog:

Comment: Apologies, stackoverflow keeps adding half finished comments that I cannot seem to delete.  As I was saying, Prolog finds the answers for variables.  Use the following query `who(lily,C,H,G, jack,germany,_,_, daisy,_,cooking,_)` and it finds the answers for the country, hobby and grade of Lily.  The underscores mean "I don't care about that variable".

Answer (score 0):

First, from filling in what we get from the first statement, we have the following.

```
(Lily, _, _, _)
(Jack,Germany, _, _)
(Daisy, _, Cooking, _)
```

Where the `_` state we don't know something. I should also say that this isn't necessarily prolog, it's more common sense than anything.

We get the phrase "Lily has better grades then the one who comes from Italy", this means that Daisy is from Germany and Lily is from the USA- since Jack's from Germany.

```
(Lily, USA, _, Grade>Daisy)
(Jack,Germany, _, _)
(Daisy, Italy, Cooking, Grade<Lily)
```

Next, we have "Jack has better grades then the one who likes reading books", which gives us the fact that he would be the football player, and the next line tells us he has the best grade. We can then promptly fill up the remained and we get:

```
(Lily, USA, Reading, Grade2)
(Jack,Germany, Football, Grade1)
(Daisy, Italy, Cooking, Grade3)
```

There could be a program written in prolog that can solve this puzzle in a very roundabout way, but this puzzle is more specific than a general case.

Comment: You just showed that you can do Prolog's job in your head :-).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take. It is essentially what @RdR has, just that I broke up the logic into more predicates, also to have a less overloaded `who()` main predicate.

```
name(lily).  % (1)
name(jack).
name(daisy).
country(italy).
country(usa).
country(germany).
hobby(football).
hobby(cooking).
hobby(reading).
grade(1).
grade(2).
grade(3).

student(N,C,H,G):-  % (2)
    name(N), country(C), hobby(H), grade(G).

permute(P,X,Y,Z):- (4)
    call(P,X), call(P,Y), call(P,Z)  % (6)
    , X\=Y, Y\=Z, X\=Z.

students(A,B,C):- (3)
    permute(name,N1,N2,N3)   % (5)
    , permute(country,C1,C2,C3)
    , permute(hobby,H1,H2,H3)
    , permute(grade,G1,G2,G3)
    , A = student(N1,C1,H1,G1)  % (7)
    , B = student(N2,C2,H2,G2)
    , C = student(N3,C3,H3,G3)
    .

who(A,B,C):-  % (8)
    students(A,B,C)
    , A = student(lily,C1,H1,G1)  % (9)
    , B = student(jack,C2,H2,G2)
    , C = student(daisy,C3,H3,G3)
    , C2 = germany                % (10)
    , H3 = cooking
    , (( C2=italy -> G1 < G2)     % (11)
      ;( C3=italy -> G1 < G3))
    , (( H1=reading -> G2 < G1)
      ;( H3=reading -> G2 < G3))
    , (( H1=football -> G1 < G2, G1 < G3)
      ;( H2=football -> G2 < G1, G2 < G3)
      ;( H3=football -> G3 < G1, G3 < G2))
    .

% Running it:
% ?- who(A,B,C).
% A = student(lily, usa, reading, 2),
% B = student(jack, germany, football, 1),
% C = student(daisy, italy, cooking, 3) ;
% false.
```

### Discussion

So there is quite a bit going on here (which intrigued me), and several choices that could be made differently (hence it is probably a nice contrast to @RdR's solution).

- As others pointed out one aspect is how to encode the information that is
  given in the problem description. You can express it very concretely (solving
  just this case), or be more general (to e.g. allow extending the problem to
  more than 3 students).
- What makes this problem different from similar others is that you have a mix
  of constraints that affect either a singel student ("Jack comes from
  Germany"), affect two students ("Lily's grades are better than the one from
  Italy"), or involves all of them ("The one liking football has the best
  grades").
- Moreover, you have disjunction contraints ("They are *all* from different
  contries, and have different hobbies"). Prolog is very good at going through
  all the possible instances of a fact, but it is more complicated to have it
  pick one instance and leave this one out for the next call of the predicate.
  This forces you to find a way to get a set of values from a fact that are
  pairwise distinct. (E.g. when Prolog settles for Lily's hobby being reading,
  it mustn't also assign reading as Jack's hobby).
- So after listing all known facts and their possible values (1) I first
  defined a predicate `student/4` (2) to simply state that a student has these
  4 properties. This produces all possible combination of students and their
  attributes, also allowing that they all have the same name, come from the
  same country, asf.
- It is a good example how to create a result set in Prolog that is way too
  large, and then try to narrow it further down (like someone else wrote).
  Further predicates could make use of this "generator" and filter more and more
  solutions from its result set. This is also easier to test, on each stage you
  can check if the intermediate output makes sense.
- In a next predicate, `students/3` (3), I try exactly what I mentioned
  earlier, creating student instances that at least don't use the same
  attribute twice (like two students having the same hobby). To achive this I
  have to run through all my attribute facts (name/1, country/1, ...), get
  three values for each, and make sure they are pairwise distinct.
- To not having to explicitly do this for each of the attributes where the
  implementation would be always the same except for the name of the
  attribute, I constructed a helper predicate `permute/4` (4) that I can pass
  the attribute name and it will look up the attribute as a fact three times,
  and makes sure the bound values are all not the same.
- So when I call `permute(name,N1,N2,N3)` in `students/3` (5) it will result in
  the lookups `call(P,X), call(P,Y), call(P,Z)` (6) which results in the same as
  invoking `name(X), name(Y), name(Z)`. (As I'm collecting 3 different values
  from always 3 facts of the same attribute this is effectively the same as doing the 3-permutations
  of a 3-value set, hence the name of helper predicate.)
- When I get to (7) I know I have distinct values for each student attribute,
  and I just distribute them across three student instances. (This should
  actually work the same without the `student/4` predicate as you can always
  make up structured terms like this on the fly in Prolog. Having the `student`
  predicate offers the additional benefit of checking that no foolish students
  can be constructed, like "student(lily, 23, asdf, -7.4)".)
- So `:- students(A,B,C).` produces all possible combinations of 3 students and
  their attributes, without using any of the involved attributes twice. Nice.
  It also wraps the (more difficult) `student()` structures in handy
  single-letter variables which makes the interface much cleaner.
- But aside from those disjointness constraints we haven't implemented any of
  the other constraint. These now follow in the (less elegant) `who/3`
  predicate (8). It basically uses `students/3` as a generator and tries to
  filter out all unwanted solutions by adding more constraints (Hence it has
  basically the same signature as `students/3`.)
- Now another interesting part starts, as we have to be able not only to filter
  individual `student` instances, but also to refer to them individually
  ("Daisy", "Jack", ...) and their respective attributes ("Daisy's hobby"
  etc.). So while binding my result variable A, B and C, I pattern-match on
  particular names. Hence the literal names `lily`, `jack` asf from (9). This
  relieves me from considering cases where Lily might come in first, or as
  second, or as third (as `students/3` would generate such permutations). So
  all 3-sets of students that don't come in that order are discarded.
- I could just as well have done this later in an explicit constraint like `N1 =
  lily` asf. I do so now enforcing the simple facts that Jack is from Germany
  and Daisy likes cooking (10). When those fail Prolog backtracks to the
  initial call to `students/3`, to get another set of students it can try.
- Now follow the additional known facts about Lily's grades, Jack's grades, and
  the grades of the football lover (11). This is particularly ugly code.
- For one, it would be nice to have helper predicate that would be able return
  the answer to the query "the student with attribute X". It would take the
  current selection of students, A, B and C, an attribute name ('country') and a
  value ('italy') and would return the appropriate student. So you could just
  query for the student from Italy, rather than assuming it must be the second
  OR the third student (as the problem description suggests that Lily herself
  is not from Italy).
- So this hypothetical helper predicate, let's call it `student_from_attribute`
  would need another helper that finds a value in a student structure by name
  and return the corresponding value. Easy in all languages that support some
  kind of object/named tuple/record where you can access fields within it by
  name. But vanilla Prolog does not. So there would be some lifting to be done,
  something that I cannot pull off of the top of my head.
- Also the `who/3` predicate could take advantage of this other helper, as you
  would need a different attribute from the student returned from
  `student_from_attribute`, like 'grade', and compare that to Lily's grade.
  That would make all those constraints much nicer, like
  `student_from_attribute([A,B,C], country, italy, S), attrib_by_name(S, grade,
  G), G1 < G`. This could be applied the same way to the reading and football
  constraint. That would not be shorter, but cleaner and more general.

I'm not sure anybody would read all this :-). Anyway, these considerations made the puzzle interesting for me.